# Ideas for Implementing Meal Plan using Magento

Tags: magento

I need help with Magento. I want to achieve something like I will have three packages for meal plans like 2meal plan, 3 meal plan etc and once user choose any meal plan then I wants to give user a way of selecting day wise ordering from given options like Monday ,Tuesday, Wednesday etc.

Please refer to image attached as I need something like that only.
[Meal Plan Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SO2R3.png)
[Meal order style example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bmA28.png)

This is what I have in mind at the moment but I am open to other ideas as well like any way of achieving the scenario I have in my mind.

Answer (score 0):

You can show Meal Plans as a category list page and Meals detail as product detail page where you can show options like Monday, Tuesday etc as a **Custom Option** where Custom Options name will be like week days and their type will me **Checkbox** and checkbox options you can provide as you want.

Comment: Okay.. I had something like this in mind before but using this idea I had doubt like how can I have condition based custom options. Like if category is 2meal plans then let user select only two options from each day. Will all this need to be custom coded or I have something in Magento to handle such situation as well? And once this will be handled I need to show additional carbs if someone selected meal with carb.